# sql case when else do nothing

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-update, case-statement

I have an ssis package that improts a csv file and then loads the data into a sql server db.
my table within sql server db has 5 fields that get populated with dates from another table. if there is a value in the 1st field then it will populate the second and so on. this works fine. i want to clear all the fields one all 5 fields are populated to start the process again.

```
UPDATE report
SET
    date1 = CASE WHEN date1 IS NOT NULL and date5 IS NOT NULL Then '' else date1  end,
    date2 =  CASE WHEN date2 IS NOT NULL and date5 IS NOT NULL Then '' else date2 end
    from report
```

my issue is with the 'else' part. i want it to be case when... then..else do nothing. at the moment its populating the else bit with the systemdate '1900-01-01' rather than leaving original value.

Comment: if `date1` and `date2`  are real `date` columns then assigning an empty string (`''`) to them makes no sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i want to set them back to null if they are populated

Comment: `''` is something different than `null` (actually it's the complete opposite of `null`). If you want to set them to `null` you need to use that:  `...then null else date1 end`

Answer (score 0):

I share the Update Table Case when if syntax for all

```
UPDATE XTABLE 
SET FieldX = (CASE WHEN FieldZ in (1,2,4,5,7,9,13) THEN '18;20' 
                   WHEN FieldZ in (15,18) THEN 730 END),
    FieldY = (CASE WHEN FieldZ in (1,2,4,5,7,9,13) THEN 2555
                   WHEN FieldZ in (15,18) THEN 730 END) 
WHERE ConditionField = 1
```